# Getting SupportFragmentManager without extending FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I want to use Fragments in my application, but I cannot extend FragmentActivity because my application already extends an activity that is part of a library. Since this means that I cannot call `getSupportFragmentManager()`, I am looking for a workaround that would allow me to use Fragments without having to extend FragmentActivity. Is it possible?

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible.
Is the library of yours or open source? You might change the Activity you extend and make it extend FragmentActivity instead of Activity

Comment: Are you sure? I read somewhere that it could be possible using some Interface magic. The library is indeed open source, but I wanted to avoid changing it so as to keep being able to update it from the repository.

Comment: Not sure how it could be done properly without extending FragmentActivity. Have you considered asking the library developer for Fragment Support?

Comment: Wouldn't that make the support package mandatory for everyone?

Comment: Good point. I don't know what library you are using. It could have a CustomActivity and a customFragmetnActivity... Don't know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your library is going to need to extend the `FragmentActivity`.

I would be concerned about a library that requires you to use their base activities anyway.

As mentioned (where possible) grab the library source code and add it as a library project to eclipse and make its activities extend the `FragmentActivity` class.

Comment: the youtube player api for android is such a library. it requires you to inherit from YouTubeBaseActivity.

Comment: @kritzikratzi Youtube api might have a `YouTubeSupportBaseActivity`. It's bad design inheriting, should always compose. Raise a bug on b.google.com

Comment: there is no such thing as YouTubeSupportBaseActivity. there is also no such thing as b.google.com